# Socket Programming sending chars

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

Hi im new to socket programming and the C language, i have the following code in my client:

```
char username[9];
        if (!strcmp(msg, "USN")){
            printf("\nUsername: \n");
            scanf("%s", username);
            write_server_msg(sockfd, username);
        }

/* Writes a message to a client socket. */
void write_server_msg(int sockfd, char *msg)
{
    int n = write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));

}
```

And i have the following code to receive my message on the server side:

```
    char *username;
            username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd[num_conn]);
            printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username); 



/* Reads a message from the server socket. */
    char *recv_msg(int sockfd)
    {    
        char *msg;

        int n = read(sockfd, msg, 9);

        printf("[DEBUG] Received message: %s\n", msg);
        return msg;
    }
```

If i put in a test username 'john', what i am getting returned on the output of my server side is 'null' can someone explain where i have gone wrong?

Comment: You’re using an uninitialized pointer for one so anything can happen

Comment: On my server side?

Comment: @JaneDoe in `recv_msg()`, `msg` is uninitialized when passed to `read()`. You need to allocate memory for `msg` to point at. Also, you are treating the return value of `recv_msg()` as a null-terminated string, but you are not transmitting a null terminator, and `read()` will not null-terminate its output for you.